# Understand the flow of executing queries in EF6 ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

**Introduction**

I have a ASP.NET MVC project build with EF6. I have added logging in my `dbContext` to see what actually is happening behind the scenes.

*Add logging*

```
public ProsecMdmEntities()
    : base("name=ProsecMdmEntities")
{
    this.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Custom log: " + s);
}
```

- Fase 1:

*Controller class:*

Below you can see a simple default controller class `SuppliersController` with only one method `Index`.

```
public class SuppliersController : Controller
{
    private ProsecMdmEntities db = new ProsecMdmEntities();

    // GET: Suppliers
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Suppliers.ToList());
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

*Result logging*

> Custom log: Opened connection at 16/07/2015 14:56:56 +02:00
>
> Custom log: SELECT 
>       [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
>       [Extent1].[SupplierCode] AS [SupplierCode], 
>       [Extent1].[SupplierName] AS [SupplierName], 
>       [Extent1].[IsNew] AS [IsNew]
>       FROM [dbo].[Suppliers] AS [Extent1] Custom log:
>
> Custom log: -- Executing at 16/07/2015 14:56:57 +02:00
>
> Custom log: -- Completed in 1 ms with result: SqlDataReader
>
> Custom log:
>
> Custom log: Closed connection at 16/07/2015 14:56:57 +02:00

- Fase 2:

*Controller class:*

Below you can see the controller class `SuppliersController` with only one method `Index` but now more complex ( added search, paging and sorting ).

```
public class SuppliersController : Controller
{
    private ProsecMdmEntities db = new ProsecMdmEntities();

    // GET: Suppliers
    public ActionResult Index(string searchFilter, string sortOrder, int? page)
    {
        // Sort
        ViewBag.IdSortParam = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "id_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.CodeSortParam = sortOrder == "code_asc" ? "code_desc" : "code_asc";
        ViewBag.NameSortParam = sortOrder == "name_asc" ? "name_desc" : "name_asc";
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;

        // Init
        IQueryable<Supplier> suppliers = null;

        // Search
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchFilter))
            suppliers = db.Suppliers.Where(
                s => s.SupplierCode.Contains(searchFilter) || s.SupplierName.Contains(searchFilter));
        else
            suppliers = db.Suppliers; // Default list

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchFilter;

        // OrderBy
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "id_desc":
                suppliers = suppliers.OrderByDescending(s => s.Id);
                break;
            case "code_asc":
                suppliers = suppliers.OrderBy(s => s.SupplierCode);
                break;
            case "code_desc":
                suppliers = suppliers.OrderByDescending(s => s.SupplierCode);
                break;
            case "name_asc":
                suppliers = suppliers.OrderBy(s => s.SupplierName);
                break;
            case "name_desc":
                suppliers = suppliers.OrderByDescending(s => s.SupplierName);
                break;
            default:
                suppliers = suppliers.OrderBy(s => s.Id);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = 50;
        int pageMax = (suppliers.Count() / pageSize) + (suppliers.Count() % pageSize > 0 ? 1 : 0);
        int pageNumber = (page == null || page <= 0 ? 1 : (page > pageMax ? pageMax : (int)page));
        return View(suppliers.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

*Result logging*

> Custom log: Opened connection at 16/07/2015 15:06:05 +02:00
>
> Custom log: SELECT 
>       [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
>       FROM ( SELECT 
>           COUNT(1) AS [A1]
>           FROM [dbo].[Suppliers] AS [Extent1]
>       )  AS [GroupBy1] Custom log:
>
> Custom log: -- Executing at 16/07/2015 15:06:05 +02:00
>
> Custom log: -- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader
>
> Custom log:
>
> Custom log: Closed connection at 16/07/2015 15:06:05 +02:00
>
> Custom log: Opened connection at 16/07/2015 15:06:05 +02:00
>
> Custom log: SELECT 
>       [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
>       FROM ( SELECT 
>           COUNT(1) AS [A1]
>           FROM [dbo].[Suppliers] AS [Extent1]
>       )  AS [GroupBy1] Custom log:
>
> Custom log: -- Executing at 16/07/2015 15:06:05 +02:00
>
> Custom log: -- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader
>
> Custom log:
>
> Custom log: Closed connection at 16/07/2015 15:06:05 +02:00
>
> Custom log: Opened connection at 16/07/2015 15:06:05 +02:00
>
> Custom log: SELECT 
>       [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
>       FROM ( SELECT 
>           COUNT(1) AS [A1]
>           FROM [dbo].[Suppliers] AS [Extent1]
>       )  AS [GroupBy1] Custom log:
>
> Custom log: -- Executing at 16/07/2015 15:06:05 +02:00
>
> Custom log: -- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader
>
> Custom log:
>
> Custom log: Closed connection at 16/07/2015 15:06:05 +02:00
>
> Custom log: Opened connection at 16/07/2015 15:06:05 +02:00
>
> Custom log: SELECT TOP (50) 
>       [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
>       [Extent1].[SupplierCode] AS [SupplierCode], 
>       [Extent1].[SupplierName] AS [SupplierName], 
>       [Extent1].[IsNew] AS [IsNew]
>       FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[SupplierCode] AS [SupplierCode], [Extent1].[SupplierName] AS [SupplierName],
>   [Extent1].[IsNew] AS [IsNew], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY
>   [Extent1].[Id] ASC) AS [row_number]
>           FROM [dbo].[Suppliers] AS [Extent1]
>       )  AS [Extent1]
>       WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 0
>       ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC Custom log:
>
> Custom log: -- Executing at 16/07/2015 15:06:05 +02:00
>
> Custom log: -- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader
>
> Custom log:
>
> Custom log: Closed connection at 16/07/2015 15:06:05 +02:00

As you can see in the second fase, you have 4 queries that have been executed. First three are the same. The last one is the one with the param filtering.

Why is this happening?

Comment: that's 3 times a count he's doing. I'm pretty sure `suppliers.Count()` actually executes a query in itself which already explains 2 of them. Then the last one is obviously the `ToList`

Comment: the strange fact is, if I set a variable`int count = suppliers.Count()` and use this everywhere in my method, I still see this 3 times...

Comment: No I am wrong now its only twice, my bad!

Comment: So this fixed it? Or there is still one too much?

Comment: Now its twice, but I only have one `.count()` function

Comment: Ok found it, I am using the library `PagedList`, inside the `.ToPagedList()` function there is also a `.count()` execution. That was our last one!

Comment: I was just looking into that too. I'll post an answer if you don't mind

Answer (score 0):

In `Linq` the `suppliers.Count()` actually executes a query in the database.

You have it twice so this explains already 2 of the duplicate.

-

**EDIT**

The last duplicate is like you said done by the `ToPagedList` method